# Minecraft 'Unbalanced Curly Brackets' Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a problem. I'm going to make "One commandblock creation", but 'Unbalanced Curly Brackets' Error pops out, when trying to use this:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:stone,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:activator_rail,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:MinecartCommandBlock,Command:gamerule commandBlockOutput false},{id:MinecartCommandBlock,Command:kill @e[type=MinecartCommandBlock,r=1]},{id:MinecartCommandBlock,Command:fill ~ ~-3 ~ ~ ~ ~ air}]}]}]}
```

I was trying to find mistake using Notepad++ but everything looked fine there...

Comment: Are you running this in a command block, or in chat?

Comment: In command block. However i find my stupid mistake - i don't know why but using "always active" does'ntt do anything, and i tried to use this instead of button.

Comment: "Always active" means that the command block stays powered. Imagine a redstone block is next to it, for example. It's more intended for repeat and chain command blocks rather than impulse.